# Is there any easy way to connect my koa.js backend with mongodb

Tags: backend, koa, koa.js

Is there any easy way to connect  my koa.js backend with mongodb

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way I implemented. There is some issue in connecting with mongodb.
https://github.com/thiva99/koa_Backend

**package.json** package.json file

```
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon server.js"
   
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.18"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "koa": "^2.13.4",
    "koa-bodyparser": "^4.3.0",
    "koa-cors": "0.0.16",
    "koa-json": "^2.0.2",
    "koa-router": "^10.1.1",
    "mongoose": "^6.4.0"
  }
}

**server.js** this is the server.js file

const koa = require('koa');
const json = require("koa-json");
const cors = require("koa-cors");
const bodyparser = require('koa-bodyparser');
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
require('dotenv').config();
const PORT = 8000;
const app = new koa();
app.use(bodyparser());
app.use(json());
app.use(cors());

//routes
const userRouter = require('./routes/userRouter');
app.use(userRouter.routes()).use(userRouter.allowedMethods());

//connecting to db 
const db = mongoose.connection;
const dbUpdate = {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
};
mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_URL, dbUpdate);

db.on('error', (err) => console.log("Error DB Not Connected" + err));
db.on('connected', () => console.log("DB Connected"));
db.on('diconnected', () => console.log("DB disconnected"));
db.on('open', () => console.log("Connection Mode! "));

//Server listening port
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log("Äpp is Started on port: " + PORT);
})

**routes** *userRouter.js*

const koaRouter = require('koa-router');
const { register, login,getAllUserDetails} = require('../api/userApi');
const userRouter = new koaRouter(({ prefix: '/user' }));

userRouter.get("/all", getAllUserDetails);
userRouter.post('/register', register);
userRouter.get('/login', login); 

module.exports = userRouter;

**model** *userModel.js* 

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const userSchema = new Schema(
    {
        name: {
            type: String,
            require: true,
        },
        email: {
            type: String,
            unique: true,
            require: true,
        },
        password: {
            type: String,
            require: true,
        },
        role: {
            type: Number,
            default: 0,
        },
    }
);
const User = mongoose.model('users',userSchema);
module.exports =User;

**api** *userApi.js*

require("dotenv").config();
const User = require("../model/userModel");

let message, status;

const register = async (ctx) => {
  try {
    const user = ctx.request.body;
    const { name, email, password, role } = user;
    const newUser = new User({
      name,
      email,
      password,
      role,
    });
    await newUser.save();
    message = "Registartion Success!";
    status = 200;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    message = error;
    status = 500;
  }
  ctx.body = message;
  ctx.status = status;
};
const login = async (ctx) => {
  try {
    const { email, password } = ctx.request.body;
    const user = await User.findOne({
      $and: [{ email: { $eq: email } }, { password: { $eq: password } }],
    });
    if (!user) {
      ctx.body = "User not fount";
      ctx.status = 400;
    } else {
        ctx.body = user;
        ctx.status=200;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    message = error.message;
    status = 500;
  }
};

const getAllUserDetails = async (ctx) => {
  try {
    const users = await User.find();
    message = users;
    status = 200;
  } catch (error) {
    message = error.message;
    status = 500;
  }
  ctx.body = message;
  ctx.status = status;
};
// const getMyDetails = async (ctx) => {
//   try {
//     const uid = await ctx.request.user.id;

//     const user = await User.findById(uid);
//     status = 200;
//     message = user;
//   } catch (error) {
//     message = error.message;
//     status = 500;
//   }
//   ctx.body = message;
//   ctx.status = status;
// };

// const getAllUserDetails = async (ctx) => {
//   try {
//     const users = await User.find();
//     message = users;
//     status = 200;
//   } catch (error) {
//     message = error.message;
//     status = 500;
//   }
//   ctx.body = message;
//   ctx.status = status;
// };

// const deleteMyAccount = async (ctx) => {
//   try {
//     await User.findByIdAndDelete(ctx.request.user.id);
//     message = "Delete Successfull";
//     status = 200;
//   } catch (error) {
//     message = error.message;
//     status = 500;
//   }
//   ctx.body = message;
//   ctx.status = status;
// };

// const deleteUserAccount = async (ctx) => {
//   try {
//     const uid = ctx.request.params.uid;
//     await User.findByIdAndDelete(uid);
//     message = "Delete Successfull";
//     status = 200;
//   } catch (error) {
//     message = error.message;
//     status = 500;
//   }
//   ctx.body = message;
//   ctx.status = status;
// };

// const updateUserAccount = async (ctx) => {
//   try {
//     const uid = ctx.request.params.uid;
//     const { role } = ctx.request.body;
//     await User.findByIdAndUpdate(uid, { role: role });
//     message = "Update Successfull";
//     status = 200;
//   } catch (error) {
//     message = error.message;
//     status = 500;
//   }
//   ctx.body = message;
//   ctx.status = status;
// };

module.exports = {
  register,
  login,
  getAllUserDetails,
//   getMyDetails,
//   getAllUserDetails,
//   deleteMyAccount,
//   deleteUserAccount,
//   updateUserAccount,
};
```